# SESSION variable with json array

Tags: php, json, session

i have an xml file in my server that i want to extract a list of IDs with php then convert the array to a JSON using `json_encode()` and put it in a `$_SESSION` variable, to make this clear my ideal JS function is:

```
function getIDs() {
    var x = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['IDs'])) echo $_SESSION['IDs']; ?>;
    if(x == '') {
        $.post('getPL.php','PL_name=cool&q=IDs',function(responseText){
            x = responseText;
        });
    }
    //some other code
    //return array; // this is an array i use later in js
}
```

in my getPL.php i have:

```
$videos_list = $theOne->parentNode->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('video');
    for ($i = 0; $i < $videos_list->length; $i++) {
        $a = $videos_list->item($i);
        $id_out = $a->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $array[$i] = $id_out;
    }
    $IDs = json_encode($array);
    $_SESSION['IDs'] = $IDs;
    echo $IDs;
    break;
```

if i alert `var x = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['IDs'])) echo $_SESSION['IDs']; ?>;` i get  `g8M8kxuaCWk,VWrBFt46J18`

but when i alert the responseText i get `["g8M8kxuaCWk","VWrBFt46J18"]`

all i want is to extract the IDs from the xml file and put them in a js array object

if there is anything need more tell me

Comment: Can you post the results of `console.log(x)` and `console.log(responseText)` instead of the `alert()`s?

Comment: Yeah, I had it the wrong way around, the `alert()` results threw me off... Strange though that jQuery did not parse the json returned from your ajax request automatically. You can also set that manually, at least when you use `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i fixed it
so `var x = '<?php if(isset($_SESSION['IDs'])) echo $_SESSION['IDs']; ?>';` would give me an array, which is what i actually want
but the `alert(resposeText);` was actually giving me a string so i  did this `JSON.parse(responseText);` 
thanks to who helped me get to this answer

after this in both cases if i `alert(obj[0]);` i get the first element so it is working

my ideal JS function becomes:

```
function getIDs() {
   var x = <?php if(isset($_SESSION['IDs'])) echo $_SESSION['IDs']; ?>;
   if(x == '') {
      $.post('getPL.php','PL_name=cool&q=IDs',function(responseText){
         x = JSON.parse(responseText); // this is the difference
      });
   }
   return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need the put quotes arround the php code in your JS like:

```
var x = '<?php if(isset($_SESSION['IDs'])) echo $_SESSION['IDs']; ?>';
```

Comment: even if i want to put quotes (which i tried) they have to be double quotes `"` not `'` to avoid conflicts with `'IDs'`

Comment: Well u can escape IDs quatos like 
$_SESSION[\'IDs\'] with this way you get json encoded string from php output. İt should be ' not " be couse of the json formated string.

Comment: thanks anyways, i fixed the problem check my answer, the problem was not with that line itwas with the responseText

Comment: you can also change the response type to json for your ajax request. Jquery will automaticly converts it to an array.